# Filemaker find latest record grouped by name in layout

Tags: date, layout, find, grouping, filemaker

I have a table of records with two fields: **City** and **ImportDate**

Example records:

London - 13/06/2016

Paris - 14/06/2016

Paris - 15/06/2016

London - 19/06/2016

London - 20/06/2016

New York - 13/06/2016

New York - 17/06/2016

---

I need to have a Filemaker layout where I display only the most recent entry for each city, so we know what imports to concentrate on as we can look down the list and see what is the oldest. In other words I want to group by City, and then display only the most recent date.

So, my layout with the above data would show:

London - 20/06/2016

New York - 17/06/2016

Paris - 15/06/2016

---

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a layout in list view with a sub-summary part (when sorted by City) and no body part. When asked, set the sub-summary part to print below the records it summarizes. Place the two fields in this part.

Sort your records by City and by ImportDate (ascending).

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, I am having another weird problem. If I set up a script with a sort step that performs exactly the same sort as I do manually, it doesn't action. I set up pause/resume to see what's going on, but the sort definitely doesn't happen even though there are no errors. And then after running the script, if I then go to the menu and choose Sort and put the same options in, it does work correctly. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Is there a way that I can order the list view by the oldest date in the found sort? At the moment it's ordered by City and giving the latest date for that city, but I need the list when viewed to be ordered by the city with the oldest latest date, if that makes sense?

Comment: You will have to add a summary field, defined as Maximum of ImportDate. Then, when sorting by City, choose to reorder by this summary field.